# How to change auto generated _id field in mongodb while importing data from csv?

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongodb-query, database

I am importing data from a `csv` file using `mongoimport`. For this I execute following command

```
mongoimport -d {databaseName} -c {collectionName}--type csv --file {fileName}  --headerline
```

It creates **auto-generated** `_id` field with the objectId value. and also creates index on it.
But I want that it should not create index on this. How can I make a compound index on `_id` and a field of that `csv` file ?

Comment: why will you want that?

Comment: coz i dont want the default id to be index.

Comment: Do you want to actually want to make a compound `_id`, or just use a different field for the primary key? If there's a more natural key in your csv file you can change the field name for that in the csv header to  `_id`.

Comment: @Stennie I want to make compound index with the default _id and one of the field of csv file.

Comment: If you want to do that, you'll have to write a custom import script in your favourite language. I'm not aware of any languages with a supported MongoDB driver that don't also have a CSV parsing module. Why do you want to use both the `_id` and the field in the CSV file, though? Is the field in the CSV not unique? Perhaps you would be better ensuring an extra index on the field after you've imported the CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting MongoDB [**documentation**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#index-type-id)

> MongoDB creates the _id index, which is an ascending unique index on the _id field, for all collections when the collection is created. You cannot remove the index on the _id field.

However you can create a compound indexes where your indexes can hold a reference to the `_id` field.

The syntax is `db.test.ensureIndex({"_id": 1, "name": 1})` for example where `name` is another field in your document. [More info](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#compound-indexes)

Comment: can we also delete the autogenerated index on a collection ?

Comment: @dasamit7 no you can't